# Texture/pattern recognition/matching int Unity?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I going to develop a game in which user draws a shape on the screen with his/her finger. Now I have some predefined shapes in form of textures already with me. What i need to do is to Detect what shape user made with his/her finger on the screen. For Example user draws an arrow on the screen, then on comparison with predefined shapes i want to know if he/she drawn an arrow. Now i need advises/suggestions the way i should go with

1) Draw a shape on screen? (Possibly with line renderer, Trail Renderer Or?)

2) Detect which shape he/she drawn? (any solution being in unity or Plugin)

Any Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to pay for it, the [FingerGestures](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/1044) package from the Asset Store seems to have what you need, plus additional features that may come in handy. I haven't used it personally, but it seems to have good reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you require to do some digital signal processing, specifically in the field of Computer Vision, I fully recommend you to use [OpenCV4Android](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.opencv.org%2Fdoc%2Ftutorials%2Fintroduction%2Fandroid_binary_package%2FO4A_SDK.html&ei=KKlvUc3HEMXStQbN9IGYDA&usg=AFQjCNGf-cNspA6D8CLLpeoy4HSTW_6_qw&bvm=bv.45368065,d.Yms), wich is a third party library written mainly in C with extensive platform support, including Android. With this you can archieve pattern matching, wich is basically what u need. I haven't used Unity but I'm sure that openCV is a powerful tool for this cases. 
Good Luck